# buttons not showing in collectionviewcell swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, button, collectionview

I am trying to interact with a button that I embedded in a collectionviewcell. But it is not showing and I am not sure what is wrong with my code.

```swift
class Classic: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return 1
    }
    

   @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!
   override func viewDidLoad()
     {
        // Register your cell
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "Subclass", bundle: nil)
        collectionView?.register(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell1")
   
     }
    
    // Collection view data source method
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
     
    // get your cell
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell1", for: indexPath) as! Subclass

      // here you will have access to your button
     cell.buttonOne.setTitle("2", for: .normal)
       
     // To handle tap on button
     cell.buttonOne.tag = indexPath.row
     cell.buttonOne.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapButton(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    return cell
}

    @objc func didTapButton(sender: UIButton) {
        print("button tapped at index:-", sender.tag)
    }
     
}


class Subclass: UICollectionViewCell{
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonOne: UIButton!
    
}
```

and here is my storyboard
[image]

As you can see in the image, I have put a button in the left-bottom cell, and the cell identifier is "cell1".

However, in the simulator
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `action` syntax is wrong.

Change `addTarget(_:action:for:)` to

```
cell.buttonOne.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapButton), for: .touchUpInside)
```

and the corresponding method to

```
@objc func didTapButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
```

Answer (score 0):

it might be that you didn't set delegation and datasource to your viewController.

assign the datasource and delegate to the viewController either in IB drag from collectionView datasource to viewController, same with delegate, or in viewDidLoad assign:
collectionView.delegate = self
collectionView.dataSource = self

don't forget to add to your viewController so it looks like :

```
class viewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource
```